# How to structure methods of classes that inherit from one BaseClass?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I have a lot of different child classes that inherit from one base class. However all the different child classes implement very similar methods. So if I want to change code in the child classes, I have to change it multiple times.

For me this sounds like bad practice and I would like to implement it correcty. But after a lot of googling I still didn't find a coherent way of how this should be done.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```py
from ABC import ABC, abstractmethod
import logging.config

class BaseModel(ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        # initialize logging
        logging.config.fileConfig(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),
            '../myconfig.ini'))
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    @abstractmethod
    def prepare_data(self):
        """
        Prepares the needed data.
        """
        self.logger.info('Data preparation started.\n')
        pass
```

So this is my BaseClass. Now from this class multiple other classes inherit the **init** and prepare_data method. The prepare_data method is very similar for every class.

```
class Class_One(BaseModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super.__init()__

    def prepare_data(self):
        super().prepare_data()
        # Some code that this method does


class Class_Two(BaseModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super.__init()__

    def prepare_data(self):
        super().prepare_data()
        # Some code that this method does
        # Code is almost the same as for Class_One


class Class_Three(BaseModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super.__init()__

    def prepare_data(self):
        super().prepare_data()
        # Some code that this method does
        # Code is almost the same as for Class_One and Class_Two

# etc.
```

I suppose you could refactor the methods into another file and then call them in each class. I would love to know how to do this correctly. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Do you actually need to define methods that do nothing but call their inherited version?

Comment: Do you mean the methods in the BaseClass? I use a BaseClass so that you have to implement the specified methods each time you create an instance of a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid there's no generic one-size-fits-all magic answer - it all really depend on the "almost" part AND on the forces that will drive change in those parts of the code. IOW, one can only really answer on a concrete example...

This being said, there are a couple lessons learned from experience, which are mostly summmarized in the famous (but unfortunately often misunderstood) [GOF "Design Patterns" book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns). If you take time to **first** read the **first** part of the book, you understand that most of (if not all) the patterns in the catalog are based on the same principle: **separate the variant from the invariant**. Once you can tell one from the other in your code (warning: there's a trap here and beginner almost always fall into it), which pattern to apply is usually obvious (sometimes to the point you only realize you used this and that patterns *after* you refactored your code).

Now as I said, there IS a trap: accidental duplication. Just because two pieces of code **look** similar doesn't mean they are duplicates - quite often, they are only "accidentally" similar *now* but the forces that will make one or the other change are mostly unrelated. If you try to immediatly refactor this code, you'll soon find yourself making the "generic" case more and more complicated to support changes that are actually unrelated, and end up with an overcomplicated, undecipherable mess that only make your code unmaintainable. So the trick here is to carefully examine the whole context, ask yourself what would drive change in one or the other "similar" parts, and if in doubt, wait until you know more. If it happens than each time you change A you have to make the exact same change in B for the exact same reasons then you DO have real duplicate.

For a more practical, short-term advise based on what we can guess from your way too abstract example (and from experience), there are at least two patterns that are most often involved in factoring out duplication in a class hierarchy: the template method and the strategy.

*NB : I said "unfortunately often misunderstood" because most people seem to jump to the patterns catalog and try to forcefit all of them in their code (whether it makes sense for the problem at hand or not), and usually by copy-pasting the canonical textbook _implementation_ (usually Java or C++ based) instead of understanding the _concept_ and implementing it in a way that's both idiomatic and adapted to the concrete use case (example: when functions are first class object, you don't necessarily need a `Strategie` class with abstract base and concrete subclasses - most often plain old callback functions JustWork(tm)).*

**EDIT** totally unrelated but this:

```
    def __init__(self):
        # initialize logging
        logging.config.fileConfig(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),
            '../myconfig.ini'))
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

is NOT how to use logging. Library code can use loggers, but **must not** configure anything - this is the application's (your main script / function / whatever) responsability, the rational being that the proper logging config depends on the context - which type of application is using the lib (a CLI app, a local GUI app and a backend web app don't have the same needs at all) and in which kind of environment (a local dev env will want much more logs than a production one for example).

Also, with the logger created with `__name__` in your base class module, all child classes will send their log to the same logger, which is certainly not what you want (you want them to have their own package / module specific loggers so you can fine tune the config per package / module).

And finally, this:

```
os.path.join(os.getcwd(),          '../myconfig.ini')
```

certainly doesn't work as you expect - your cwd can be just **anything** at this point and you have no way of knowing in advance. If you want to reference a path relative to the current file's directory, you want `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))`. And of course adding system specific path stuff (ie "../") in a `os.path.join()` call totally defeats the whole point of using `os.path`.

Comment: Wow thanks for this great and detailed answer! I would never have imagined to get such a thorough feedback. Sorry if my example is too abstract. This is probably because I'm not really experienced in OOP development and I could not find a way to describe my issue nicely and in a more concrete way. This was also my first question ever on StackOverflow so I will try to do better next time!

Comment: @theotrama glad I could help - and feel free to upvote and/or accept the answer if it solves your problem.